# Managing Overflow with Hardware Timestamp

Tags: swift

I'm currently working with hardware that reports a 16 bit timestamp where LSB = 50us. The means that the max range is about ~3.25s. I'm trying to find an efficient way to convert an array of timestamps into a continuous time vector with a much larger range and am struggling with how to handle overflows of the timestamp in an efficient way.

Please note I'm new to swift and working with data at the byte level like this.

This is my current approach but it feels sloppy.

```
let timeVectorRaw: [UInt16] = <time values>

// First timestamp will not necessarily be zero, so need to record the value of the first entry which will be subtracted later so the time vector starts at zero
timeOffsetInt = Int(timeVectorRaw[0])
// Last timestamp (Uint16) (not scaled/no offset)
var lastRawValue: UInt16 = 0

var lastWholeNumberValue: Int = 0

for timeValue in timeVectorRaw {
    // if time vector is empty or if timestamp hasn't overflowed yet, no adjustment necessary
    if timeVectorWrapped.isEmpty || timeVectorWrapped.last! < timeValue {
        timeVectorWrapped.append(Int(timeValue))
    }
    else if timeValue < lastRawValue {
        // Essentially floor(last time value / Uint16 max value)
        lastWholeNumberValue = timeVectorWrapped.last! + 65536 - ((timeVectorWrapped.last!) % 65536)
        timeVectorWrapped.append(Int(timeValue) + lastWholeNumberValue)

    }
    else {
        timeVectorWrapped.append(Int(timeValue) + lastWholeNumberValue)
    }
    lastRawValue = timeValue
}

for timeValueWrap in timeVectorWrapped {
    // subtract offset and multiply by scale factor (50us/lsb)
    timeVector.append(Float((timeValueWrap - timeOffsetInt)) * 0.000050)
}
```

Comment: Just to be clear: the above code works and does what you want, and you just want to make it more efficient (and possibly nicer to look at)?

Comment: Yes, this currently works. I just have a feeling that there must be a better way to do it. I looked for quite a while to see if someone had already solved this but came up empty handed (though to be fair, there are probably better words to describe this scenario). Eventually I will want to do this conversion in real time (easy enough to adapt this - I don't need help with that) and the sample rates will be quite high which is why I think efficiency is important

Comment: Added comments to hopefully make this more clear